# drupal's taxonomy: access to private files by taxonomy?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

in my e-learning website i sell my tutorials. my files are there in private folder and after paying for each set of files, users have access to download that specific set of files...
to implement that; so far i used this module: "Private files download permission" = Allows by-user and by-role downloads from private file system directories.
so for each set of files i have to created a separate role!

**my problem:** now i have so many roles and it is getting more difficult to organize them!
now i am thinking of other solutions such as using taxonomy!
i can create a form to upload a file to private folder and assign a taxonomy to it!
1- but i don't have a clear idea how to assign this taxonomy to a user after paying?
2-how can i let him download from private folder if that user has the proper taxonomy?

**my question:** is there any module which can do half the job at least? or if there is no module to help me...can i use Rules module to check if a user a certain taxonomy or not? 
if you have any good way to implement this issue plz share it with me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access  or Organic Groups. https://drupal.org/project/og

Comment: i think both are based on roles! each role can have several taxonomies. any user who is in that role can download all those taxonomies!
this is not what i want because i have to have so many taxonomies again.
i need something which is based on taxonomy.
1- i can assign one taxonomy to a user
2- for downloading it checks whether the user has that taxonomy or not